# fa-search FontAwesome icon getting chopped

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using 4.2 FontAwesome and few icons are getting chopped as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c5aps25u/. Font used is Arial 12px. The `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>` icon is getting chopped on top. Why is this happening and how to resolve this? I did try setting the line-height to a greater value to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just rendering problem which differ from the browser and the font-size. To avoid this, you must either rescale the `font-size` of the `icon` and try looking in every different browser.

I used Chrome, and it looks like not chopped, but in FF it looks clearly that it's chopped with `font-size: 12px`.